# How to configure spring interceptor to get called with every request

Tags: java, node.js, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I want to configure my spring interceptor in such a way that with every request it should get called.

- I am using interceptor in API-GATEWAY **(Spring-Boot)**
- From API-GATEWAY I am calling other microservices.
- The call's to other microservices from API-GATEWAY is working fine.
- Other Services which I am calling are Node.js Service, on the other hand, my API-Gateway is in spring boot.
- All the services (Node.js + Spring-Boot) are running on **Docker Container**.

I am facing an issue in Interceptor. I want to configure it in such a way that with every request it should be called the `preHandle()` and perform the operations that I have written in it.

I have notice one issue that I want to mention here.

**If the services which I am calling is stopped (Not Running), Interceptor is working properly and giving me a response like somename-service not found.
If the same services are running at this time Interceptor is not executed.**

Here is my code snippet

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@Configuration
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private TokenValidateInterceptor tokenValidateInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(tokenValidateInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");


    }
```

Interceptor

```
@Component
public class TokenValidateInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        LOG.info("#### Starting TokenValidateInterceptor.preHandle ####");

        String apiKey = null;
        try {
            apiKey = request.getHeader("apikey");

            LOG.info("The request come with apikey ======" + apiKey);

            LOG.info("Actual apikey ======" + azureApikey);


}
```

Comment: what does your TokenValidateInterceptor look like ?

Comment: I have updated my question and put the TokenValidateInterceptor code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this interceptor to your dispatcher xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" p:interceptors-ref="tokenInterceptor" />

    <bean id="tokenInterceptor" class="yourpackage.TokenValidateInterceptor" />

</beans>
```

There are few nice samples here:

- [Spring MVC Interceptot](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-interceptor-tutorial/)
- [Dzone Spring Interceptor](https://dzone.com/sites/all/files/SpringExample9.zip)

Comment: I am using Spring-Boot. So there is no `dispatcher-servlet` required.

Comment: Could you share the complete code of your interceptor? I would be nice to check how it is calling the service...

Comment: Interceptor is not calling the other node js services. Its get call using the Zuell routes configure in bootstrap.yml. I am sure there is no problem is service call. The problem is with the intercepting the request in ablove mention class

Answer (score 0):

First make a WebMvc Config class as shown below

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
    }
```

Create Request Interceptor i.e. MyInterceptor by extending HandlerInterceptorAdapter

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response, 
    Object handler, 
    ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        ......Write your business logic here...........}
}
```

for more information you can refer [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use HttpFilter in this case, it has doFilter method, just override that method and execute your code.